# Auto-completion or Suggest

Tags: algorithms, search

How does Google or amazon implement the auto-suggestion at their search box. I am looking for the most used algorithm with technology stack.

PS: I have searched over the net and found [this](http://www.quora.com/Google-Autocomplete/How-does-Googles-autocomplete-feature-work) and [this](http://googleblog.blogspot.in/2010/09/google-instant-behind-scenes.html) and many many more. But I am more interested in not what they do but how they do it. NoSQL database to store the phases? or is it sorted or hashed according to keyword's? So to rephrase the question: Given the list of different searches ignoring personalization, geographic-location etc, How do they store, manage and suggest it so well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe Google still uses [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) for their web indexing, and thus probably the same for their auto complete. But they keep on redeveloping their solutions, as their data-set obviously increases and a certain solution might not be working at a certain point of time for them anymore.